# How to prevent USB-connected printer from causing delay in pre-POST startup?

Tags: boot, usb, uefi

The (intermittently-occurring) symptom: After pressing the power button there's one quick beep as normal, but then there's a long-ish delay (1~2 minutes) before the second beep that indicates the start of the self test and the appearance of the POST screen.

The system is homebuilt based on AMD Ryzen 7 5700G with ASUS B550M-PLUS motherboard.  It's running Windows 11, but the problem occurs before Windows is involved.

After months of thinking there was a faulty memory module or some other hardware problem with my build, I finally associated the symptoms with my printer of all things.  If the printer is powered down (and not just in standby/sleep), the computer starts normally, and there is only a few seconds delay between the initial beep and the second one at start of the POST.

The printer is a Brother MFC-J895DW multifunction, connected by USB.

Other potentially-helpful information:  I was clued in to the involvement of the printer when I noticed that DaVinci Resolve (video production software) was hanging on startup when my printer was powered on. On the support forum for Resolve, it was suggested that the software was scanning USB for storage devices. This printer includes a USB and SD port on the front for saving scans or printing photos.  These are accessible by Windows as removable drives. To mitigate the problems with Resolve starting, I started powering down the printer after each use, which also corrected the  system startup issue.

Any idea of UEFI settings (or other changes) that might stop the problem outright without having to power down the printer all the time?

Comment: Do you *use* the printer's storage-device interfaces? Does it have any firmware updates available?

Comment: Consider a hardware fix: a mechanical USB switch, e.g., https://www.amazon.com/Switch-Extension-Upgraded-Strips-System/dp/B07T9BRNHW/ref=sr_1_5 . If the switch only cuts the *power* to the USB device, it might, or might not work; test to see if it helps booting.

Comment: Have a look here: https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/misc/Manual/PRIME_TUF_GAMING_B550_Series_BIOS_EM_WEB_EN.pdf?model=TUF%20GAMING%20B550M-PLUS and search for "Fast" and "USB" separately, read over the configuration options, set them accordingly with various variations, and see if that makes any difference at power cycle. Anything applicable in the firmware settings to increase performance or similar type options could help. Page 21, 22, 30, 32, and 42 options with cursory look of potential relevance for a starting point things you can do now, process of elimination time... Good luck!

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle I went through all of the boot configuration options earlier (before I realized the printer was involved).

Comment: @u1686_grawity Yes, I use the storage interfaces when I want to scan something to a flash drive without turning on the computer.  The printer updates its firmware over WiFi automatically.  My desktop PC has no WiFi.  I could connect the printer by wired ethernet, but that disables its Wifi and then we couldn't print from a laptop/tablet.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I think turning off the printer is a lot easier than adding another switch.

Comment: Glad to be of service.... chugga chugga choo choo!!!

Answer (score 1):

I decided to have a look in the UEFI setup to see what USB options are available.  They were:

- Power Delivery in Soft Off state (Enabled)
- Legacy USB Support (Enabled)
- USB Device Enable (Enabled)
- Enable/Disable for individual ports.

The [documentation](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/misc/Manual/PRIME_TUF_GAMING_B550_Series_BIOS_EM_WEB_EN.pdf) (p. 32) on "Legacy USB Support" is a bit vague: I couldn't tell whether setting it to "Disabled" would only prevent booting a legacy OS from a USB device (which would be fine), of if it would prevent USB devices from functioning altogether outside the UEFI setup.

Anyway I changed this setting to "Auto" and it seems to have worked.

Comment: So my whole comment detail on the pointers I gave you for starting points actually helped you pinpoint and expedite your own self-service resolution!! That's fabulous and good job with figuring out which setting (or combination) was needed to resolve your problem with everything that's available to you with that configuration!! Awesome news!

Comment: "Legacy USB support" as the name implies, is necessary for proper initialization of OLD USB peripherals only. "Auto", whenever available, should always be set. Disabling it, in your case, would have the same effect, and indeed it speeds up the POST as you wanted and confirmed.

Answer (score -1):

This problem is happening in the BIOS/UEFI with its
interaction with the printer, so the first action
should be to update all the involved software/firmware.

You may find downloads for this printer on the
[MFC-J895DW Downloads page](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=us_ot&lang=en&prod=mfcj895dw_us_eu),
where you choose your operating system to get a list of the
downloads, although the printer firmware is an independent
download.

Download for the BIOS/UEFI you'll find on the website of the
manufacturer of the motherboard.

You might also examine the BIOS/UEFI for any factors that might
influence that interaction, although there wouldn't be
many of them.

For the hardware angel, you could try other USB ports.
Testing the printer on another computer will give more
information, but might not point to the problem.

If all this does not improve the problem, I'm afraid that
you'll need to just work around it by turning
it off and on.

Comment: I checked and the printer already had the latest firmware.

Comment: I have fleshed out some more my answer. But as this is happening inside the BIOS/UEFI, your options are limited.